# Sending Gmail in VB and Having The Body as a Rich Textbox

Tags: vb.net

Hello and greetings to all, I need some help. Below is my following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")

    Mail.Subject = "Security Update"
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("XXXX@gmail.com")
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("XXXX@gmail.com", "XXXX")

    Mail.To.Add("XXX@gmail.com")

    Mail.Body = "Test"

    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
End Sub
```

However, I get the following Error When Ran: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

The Password Is The Same To Login and is correct. What am I doing wrong? Also, I have a rich text box that I would like to be the body of the E-mail. I do not know how to do this. Please help.

Comment: SMTP.Port is not asking for a string.

Comment: You need to use SSL, use the right port, allow connections from less secure apps, and convert your content to HTML.

Comment: Thank You. I have fixed with both of your responses. My next question is, how can i place the Mail.Body to be the rich text box?

Comment: An email can either be plain text or HTML. RTF is not supported. If you want to send just the text display in your `RichTextBox` then you assign the contents of its `Text` property to the `Body` of your email.  If you have formatted text in your control and you want that formatting reflected in the email then you'll need to convert the RTF to HTML, so you'd better get researching how to do that.